# How to read a previously generated list of column names automatically from a database and save it individually?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database, data-science

After a long search I can't find a solution or similar questions.
I have read about querys in pandas but they refer to explicit instructions and not to a previously generated list of names.

To define my question more explicitly, I want to develop a kind of loop that runs through a list of column names and reads and saves each one individually with e.g. pd.read_sql().
This would be for example like:

```
pd.read_sql(SELECT [temperature_1], [temperature_2], ... FROM Raummonitoring)
```

Only that instead of writing out every single column name, I want to run through them automatically with a function like pd.read_sql from a list because before that some Filters apply that already create a list themselves.
Please let me know if I am unclear, I will try to be more precise.

Comment: not sure if I got it right. you can create a engine `dbEngine=sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')` and then use SQL like `c1=['ID','NAME']
c2=['SALARY']
df=pd.read_sql_table(table_name='COMPANY',con=dbEngine,columns=c1+c2)`

Comment: what typ has c1 in your example ?

Comment: its the column name from my list right ? i got TypeError: read_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Raummonitoring' I have overwritten table_name with Raummonitoring if its righ

Comment: yes, c1 and c2 are two lists with the column names. in my example table name is `COMPANY' and it will select `['ID', 'NAME', 'SALARY']`  from the table. so the data df will be equivalent to `select 'ID', 'NAME', 'SALARY' from COMPANY'

Comment: syntax for MySQL-Connector: mysql+mysqlconnector://<user>:<password>@<host>[:<port>]/<dbname>

Comment: okay i understand how you mean that. Unfortunately, this is not quite the approach I am aiming for. I have already included the column names in a list. I would like to use this list now to read out from the database exactly these columns which are in my list.